# Play production environment generation throws warnings

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

Every time I run `dist` to generate the production environment I get the following warnings:

> [warn] Scala version was updated by one of library dependencies:
>
> [warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.11.0 -> 2.11.8
>
> [warn] To force scalaVersion, add the following:
>
> [warn]  ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
>
> [warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

Now, in `build.sbt` I have the following line:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
```

I changed it from "2.11.8" when I installed a `cats` library as the installation said that Scala version was migrated to 2.11.12.

Should I ignore the `dist` message?

Comment: have you tried the suggested: `ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }`? This should be save as your version is the newest.

Comment: I added that statement and it worked, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is described here: [Github sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2894)

The issue is still open.

It proposes:

> Reflecting the scalaVersion mediator, we could issue a warning like:

```
[warn] Some library dependencies use a newer Scala version than this project: 
[warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.0 -> 2.12.1 
[warn] We recommend you upgrade to the latest scalaVersion patch: 
[warn]  scalaVersion := 2.12.1 if we know that the mediator is turned on.
```

Comment: what's the `scalaVersion mediator` ?

Comment: this is just an excerpt from the open issue. See the link in my answer for the whole discussion. (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2894)